# Program uses too much memory

Tags: c#

I load into dataGridView 30 rows (text and image from paths) from database. Each image has around 45-60kB.
When my program runs, it uses 30mb RAM. If I press `button3_Click_2`(load next 30 rows), it will use +20mb RAM more, each time... 
How can I solve my problem?

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  SQL.Data_from_DB(0); //Load data from DB into Lists 
  LoadTable();    //Load data from Lists into DataGridView
 }
```

---

```
 public void LoadTable()
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        VS.count_list = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< 30; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[VS.count_list].Cells[0].Value = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(Convert.ToInt32(SQL.Date[i], 10));
            dataGridView1.Rows[VS.count_list].Cells[1].Value = SQL.Text[i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[VS.count_list].Cells[2].Value =SQL.Likes[i];
            dataGridView1.Rows[VS.count_list].Cells[3].Value = SQL.Reposts[i];
            if (SQL.Image[i] != "-")
            {
                try
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[VS.count_list].Cells[5].Value = LoaDimg(SQL.Image[i]);
                }
                catch
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[VS.count_list].Cells[5].Value = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[VS.count_list].Cells[5].Value = null;
            }
            VS.count_list++;  
        }
    }
```

---

```
 private Image LoaDimg(string path)
        {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\1\\" + path + ".jpg");
        return bitmap;
    }
```

---

```
 public static void Data_from_DB(int inp_num)
 {
        using (SqlConnection connection = GetConection())
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Id BETWEEN @start AND @end";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", inp_num + 1);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end",   inp_num + 30);
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read()) { 
                    Date.Add((String.Format("{0}", reader["Post_Date"].ToString())));
                    Text.Add((String.Format("{0}", reader["Post_Text"].ToString())));
                    Likes.Add((String.Format("{0}", reader["Post_Likes"].ToString())));
                    Reposts.Add((String.Format("{0}", reader["Post_Reposts"].ToString())));
                    Image.Add((String.Format("{0}", reader["Post_Image"].ToString())));
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

---

```
 private void button3_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            SQL.Date.Clear(); //Clear Lists
            SQL.Text.Clear();
            SQL.Likes.Clear();
            SQL.Reposts.Clear();
            SQL.Image.Clear();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            row_num += 30;
            SQL.Data_from_DB(row_num); //Load next 30
            LoadTable(); 
 }
```

Comment: A WinForms application that displays a bunch of images using ~40 MB is not at all unusual. Are you actually getting out of memory errors? Is the program crashing? What is the problem here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does .NET reserve so much memory for my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670064/why-does-net-reserve-so-much-memory-for-my-application)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to throw out the old data every time you load a new set of 30 rows.  If so, that would be a good time to call Dispose() on all the images you've allocated for the old 30 rows.

Comment: Your images are icons, right? Because this is a VERY small size for a  BITMAP - and that is the only thing windows can show. If those are jpg - they get expanded to Bitmaps on load. Here goes your memory.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't have any errors, but after 4th click on button it uses 120mb and so on...  And I still have 30 images that are changing on every click in DataGridView.

Comment: @adv12 Those are jpgs with ImageLayout = Stretch

Comment: Fyi, you don't need `reader.Close` and `connection.Close` since you're using the `using`-statement. How have you measured the memory consumption at all?

Comment: The garbage collector will only kick in when it thinks it should. Maybe you are still good despite the growth.. But do watch those gdi handles and gdi-heap!

Comment: 30 images, jpb of 50kb that get expanded into SIGNIFICANT bitmaps, replaced every second. Why do you wonder about memory consumption?

Comment: Why do you use `VS.count_list` at all if you are already in a `for`-loop? Don't use static variables if you can use local variables.